# Autoformat UITextfield in phone number format XXX-XXX-XXXX in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, formatting, uitextfield, swift4.2

I'm trying to autoformat my textfield in the format XXX-XXX-XXXX. The rules are that it should be in the format as mentioned and the first number should be greater than zero and should be of max 10 digits, the regex for this is already added in my function. Below are the methods I'm using

```
@IBAction func validateAction(_ sender: Any) {
        guard let phoneNumber = phoneNumber.text else {return }
        if validatePhoneNumber(phoneNumber: phoneNumber) {
            errorMessage.text = "Validation successful"
        } else {
            errorMessage.text = "Validation failed"
        }

    }

    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

            guard let currentText = textField.text as NSString? else {return true}
            let textString = currentText.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
            if textField == phoneNumber {
                return textField.updatePhoneNumber(string, textString)
            }else{
                return true
            }
    }

    func validatePhoneNumber(phoneNumber: String) -> Bool {
        let phoneRegex: String = "^[2-9]\\d{2}-\\d{3}-\\d{4}$"
        return NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", phoneRegex).evaluate(with: phoneNumber)
    }

extension UITextField {

    func updatePhoneNumber(_ replacementString: String?, _ textString: String?) -> Bool {
        guard let textCount = textString?.count else {return true}
        guard let currentString = self.text else {return true}
        if replacementString == "" {
            return true
        } else if textCount == 4 {
            self.text =  currentString + "-"
        } else if textCount == 8 {
            self.text = currentString + "-"
        } else if textCount > 12 || replacementString == " " {
            return false
        }
        return true
    }

}
```

This works to some extent, now the issue is, user can manually intervene and disrupt the format for eg: if I entered, 234-567-8990, user can place the cursor just before 5 and backspace and type in at the end or between like 567-89900000 or 234567-8990. By validating the regular expression it will give an error but I want to re-adjust the format as user types in. For eg: in the earlier scenario if the user is on cursor before 5 and backspaces it should not remove the dash (-) but just removes 4 and re-adjust format like 235-678-990. Is there any simple way to do this? Any help is appreciated

Comment: You can use https://github.com/luximetr/AnyFormatKit

Answer (score 1):

I use this extension for String. It's small and real helpful.

```
extension String {
 func applyPatternOnNumbers(pattern: String, replacmentCharacter: Character) -> String {
    var pureNumber = self.replacingOccurrences( of: "[^0-9]", with: "", options: .regularExpression)
    for index in 0 ..< pattern.count {
        guard index < pureNumber.count else { return pureNumber }
        let stringIndex = String.Index(encodedOffset: index)
        let patternCharacter = pattern[stringIndex]
        guard patternCharacter != replacmentCharacter else { continue }
        pureNumber.insert(patternCharacter, at: stringIndex)
    }
    return pureNumber
}
```

just set a needed mask

```
text.applyPatternOnNumbers(pattern: "+# (###) ###-##-##", replacmentCharacter: "#")
```

and that's all

Comment: Could you guide me where exactly should I add this in my code?

Comment: @SonuP there are some variants, for example you can format your text with textfield listener `textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange), for: .editingChanged)` and listen it here `func textFieldDidChange(_ textfield: UITextfield)` and in the body of last function format your text, like this `textfield.text = textfield.text.applyPatternOnNumbers("somePattern")`

Answer (score 0):

@SonuP very good question. I believe you want to format the phone and also **keep the cursor in correct position**. If so, then this task is slightly more complex than just formatting. You need to reformat the code and update the cursor position.
Note that my solution follows the specific formatting and if it does not match yours, then tweak the code slightly:

**Swift 5**

```
    public func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        var text = textField.text ?? ""
        text.replaceSubrange(range.toRange(string: text), with: string)
        if let phone = (textField.text ?? "").replacePhoneSubrange(range, with: string) {
            // update text in the field
            textField.text = text
            // update cursor position
            if text.count == range.location + string.count || text.hasSuffix(")") && text.count == range.location + string.count + 1 { // end
                if phone.hasSuffix(")") {
                    textField.setCursor(phone.count - 1)
                }
                else {
                    textField.setCursor(phone.count)
                }
            }
            else {
                textField.setCursor(min(range.location + string.count, phone.count-1))
            }
        }
        return false
    }
```

Also you will need the following extensions:

```
// MARK: - Helpful methods
extension NSRange {

    /// Convert to Range for given string
    ///
    /// - Parameter string: the string
    /// - Returns: range
    func toRange(string: String) -> Range<String.Index> {
        let range = string.index(string.startIndex, offsetBy: self.lowerBound)..<string.index(string.startIndex, offsetBy: self.upperBound)
        return range
    }

    static func fromRange(_ range: Range<String.Index>, inString string: String) -> NSRange {
        let s = string.distance(from: string.startIndex, to: range.lowerBound)
        let e = string.distance(from: string.startIndex, to: range.upperBound)
        return NSMakeRange(s, e-s)
    }
}

// MARK: - Helpful methods
extension String {

    /// Raplace string in phone
    public func replacePhoneSubrange(_ range: NSRange, with string: String) -> String? {
        if let phone = self.phone { // +11-111-111-1111 (111)
            var numberString = phone.phoneNumber // 111111111111111
            let newRange = self.toPhoneRange(range: range)
            numberString.replaceSubrange(newRange.toRange(string: phone), with: string)
            return numberString.phone
        }
        return nil
    }

    /// Phone number string
    public var phoneNumber: String {
        let components = self.components(
            separatedBy: CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted)
        var decimalString = NSString(string: components.joined(separator: ""))
        while decimalString.hasPrefix("0") {
            decimalString = decimalString.substring(from: 1) as NSString
        }
        return String(decimalString)
    }

    /// Get phone range
    public func toPhoneRange(range: NSRange) -> NSRange {
        let start = range.location
        let end = start + range.length
        let s2 = self.convertPhoneLocation(location: start)
        let e2 = self.convertPhoneLocation(location: end)
        return NSRange(location: s2, length: e2-s2)
    }

    /// Get cursor location for phone
    public func convertPhoneLocation(location: Int) -> Int {
        let substring = self[self.startIndex..<self.index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: location)]
        return String(substring).phoneNumber.count
    }
}

// MARK: - Helpful methods
extension UITextField {

    /// Set cursor
    ///
    /// - Parameter position: the position to set
    func setCursor(_ position: Int) {
        if let startPosition = self.position(from: self.beginningOfDocument, offset: position) {
            let endPosition = startPosition
            self.selectedTextRange = self.textRange(from: startPosition, to: endPosition)
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - Helpful methods
extension String {

    /// phone formatting
    public var phone: String? {
        let components = self.components(
            separatedBy: CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted)
        var decimalString = NSString(string: components.joined(separator: ""))
        while decimalString.hasPrefix("0") {
            decimalString = decimalString.substring(from: 1) as NSString
        }

        let length = decimalString.length
        let hasLeadingOne = length > 0 && length == 11
        let hasLeadingTwo = length > 11

        if length > 15 {
            return nil
        }
        var index = 0 as Int
        let formattedString = NSMutableString()

        if hasLeadingOne || hasLeadingTwo {
            let len = hasLeadingTwo ? 2 : 1
            let areaCode = decimalString.substring(with: NSMakeRange(index, len))
            formattedString.appendFormat("+%@-", areaCode)
            index += len
        }
        if (length - index) > 3 {
            let areaCode = decimalString.substring(with: NSMakeRange(index, 3))
            formattedString.appendFormat("%@-", areaCode)
            index += 3
        }
        if length - index == 4 && length == 7 { // xxx-xxxx
            let prefix = decimalString.substring(with: NSMakeRange(index, 4))
            formattedString.append(prefix)
            index += 4
        }
        else if length - index > 3 {// xxx-xxx-x...
            let prefix = decimalString.substring(with: NSMakeRange(index, 3))
            formattedString.appendFormat("%@-", prefix)
            index += 3
        }
        if length - index == 4 { // xxx-xxx-xxxx
            let prefix = decimalString.substring(with: NSMakeRange(index, 4))
            formattedString.append(prefix)
            index += 4
        }

        // format phone extenstion
        if length - index > 4 {
            let prefix = decimalString.substring(with: NSMakeRange(index, 4))
            formattedString.appendFormat("%@ ", prefix)
            index += 4
        }

        let remainder = decimalString.substring(from: index)
        if length > 12 {
            formattedString.append("(\(remainder))")
        }
        else {
            formattedString.append(remainder)
        }
        return (formattedString as String).trimmingCharacters(in: NSCharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this in textfield delegate method :

```
 func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    if range.length > 0 {
      return true
    }
    if string == "" {
      return false
    }
    if range.location > 11 {
      return false
    }
    var originalText = textField.text
    let replacementText = string.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")

    if !CharacterSet.decimalDigits.isSuperset(of: CharacterSet(charactersIn: replacementText)) {
      return false
    }

    if range.location == 3 || range.location == 7 {
      originalText?.append("-")
      textField.text = originalText
    }
    return true
}
```